# Ошибки при компоновке cpp фалов в проекте

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c++builder

При сборке проекта возникли ошибки при компоновке файлов. В чём может быть ошибка?

Ошибки:
[image: Ошибки при сборке проекта]

Проект содержит следующие файлы с кодом:

Source.cpp

```
#include "COMProcess.h"
int main()
{
    char a[] = "COM3";
    OpenCom(a);
    WriteCom("3", 1);
    while (true)
    {
        ReadCOM();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

COMProcess.h

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

extern HANDLE hSerial;

void ReadCOM()
{
    DWORD iSize;
    char sReceivedChar;
    while (true)
    {
        ReadFile(hSerial, &sReceivedChar, 1, &iSize, 0);  // получаем 1 байт
        if (iSize > 0)   // если что-то принято, выводим
            std::cout << sReceivedChar;
    }
}

DWORD WriteCom(const char* msg, int sizeMsg) {
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;    // тут будет количество собственно переданных байт
    BOOL iRet = WriteFile(hSerial, msg, sizeMsg, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    return dwBytesWritten;
}

void OpenCom(const char* msg) {
    size_t newsize = strlen(msg) + 1;
    wchar_t* port = new wchar_t[newsize];
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, port, newsize, msg, _TRUNCATE);

    LPCTSTR portName = port;
    hSerial = ::CreateFile(portName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            std::cout << "serial port does not exist.\n";
        }
        std::cout << "some other error occurred.\n";
    }
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        std::cout << "getting state error\n";
    }
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        std::cout << "error setting serial port state\n";
    }
}
```

Насколько понял, данная ошибка возникла из-за использования глобальной переменной `extern HANDLE hSerial;`. Логично было бы передовать её из функции в функцию, но как можно исправить эти ошибки без таких методик?

Comment: COMProcess.h есть, а реализации - нет (cpp или lib)

Comment: В заголовочном файле должны быть только объявления, а не определения. Иначе в каждом из файлов будут скомпилированные функции, как у вас (ошибки *уже определен*). А для объявлений должно быть определение в одном из файлов реализации. Т.е. в одном из .cpp-файлов должно быть `HANDLE hSerial;`

Comment: Делайте все определения `inline`, тогда и дополнительные .cpp файлы не понадобятся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первые ошибки были из-за того, что вы определения функций записали в хедер файл. При повторному обращению возникает ошибка, что вы создаёте функцию с таким-же именем.

Эти функции нужно записать в отдельный **.cpp** файл. А в хедере оставить только предварительные объявления.

```
void OpenCom(const char* msg);
DWORD WriteCom(const char* msg, int sizeMsg);
void ReadCOM(void);
```

---

Вторая ошибка из-за декларации **extern HANDLE hSerial;** которая намекает компилятору, что существует переменная где-либо в коде.

Но вы не определили нигде переменную **HANDLE hSerial;**, например в **Source.cpp** файле и по-этому компилятор не может её найти.

---

При одновременном стучании на разные порты будут большие проблемы из-за одной глобальной переменной **extern HANDLE hSerial;**

Правильнее передавать это значение аргументом. Примерно так :

```
HANDLE OpenCom(const char* msg);
DWORD WriteCom(HANDLE,const char* msg, int sizeMsg);
void ReadCOM(HANDLE);
```

И пользоваться простой локальной переменной :

```
#include "COMProcess.h"
int main(){
    char a[] = "COM3";
    HANDLE const h = OpenCom(a);
    WriteCom( h ,"3", 1);
    while (true) {
        ReadCOM( h );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для тех кто первый арз сталкивается я трудностми в многофайловом проекте рекомендую посмотреть [это видео](https://youtu.be/pAxEfF2yVlM)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)